# Show and hide a map element in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I'm creating a game. The user is given 6 letters and they have to make as many words as possible. When each letter is clicked it shows in the display box. I want the clicked letter to disappear from the available letter row so that players can't use the same letter twice. I used `.map()` to display the 6 letters. How can I make one of them disappear after being clicked?

```
<div className="letter_wrapper">
  {slicedLetters.map((l, i) => {
    return (
      <p key={i} className="letter_container">
        <span onClick={getLetterInput} className="letter">
          {l}
        </span>
      </p>
    )
  })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create two states for this one being the list of all options of letters and the second state for storing the clicked letters.

```
const [slicedLetters, setSlicedLetters] = useState(['a', 'b', 'c']);
const [selectedSlicedLetters, setSelectedSlicedLetters] = useState(['a']);
```

Once the above states are created next while looping through the array using map first you should filter out the selectedSlicedLetters using a filter function.

```
const remainingLetters = slicedLetters.filter(el => !selectedSlicedLetters.includes(el));
```

Now the remainingLetters is an **array** which will contain all the letters that are not selected.

Now you can loop through the remainingLetters like below:

```
<div className="letter_wrapper">
  {remainingLetters .map((l, i) => (
      <p
      key={i}
      className="letter_container">
      <span
      onClick={getLetterInput}
      className="letter">
      {l}
      </span>
      </p>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: my jaw dropped when it worked. Thank you so much. This has been racking my brain for days

Comment: Glad it could be of help, would you mind upvoting the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to put `slicedLetters` in a state variable, like:

```
const [slicedLetters, setSlicedLetters] = useState(<initial value>);
```

Then in the `onClick` handler `getLetterInput` you update the `slicedLetters` variable and remove the element you want, like:

```
getLetterInput() {
    ... current logic

    setSlicedLetters((_slicedLetters) =>
        _slicedLetters.filter((__slicedLetter) => {
             // Here you need the logic to exclude the letter
        })
    )
}
```

The reason I used `_slicedLetters` inside `setSlicedLetters` is because this operation is an async function (and React batches several of such operations together if required). Hence, its better to not refer to the value `slicedLetters` within `setSlicedLetters`.

After the `setSlicedLetters` is performed, React will re-render the component by calling the below again (with the updated `slicedLetters` value),

```
slicedLetters.map((l, i) => {})
```

Now, the letter is removed from the UI!

Comment: Ahhhh I see what you mean. I will go try this and report back. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Robin, this didn't work for me but I'm pretty sure it's because I couldn't get the logic right. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Yes sorry! They just gave me the ability to upvote a few hours ago.

Comment: Hi Robin, can I ask you another question about this solution and the others listed below?

Comment: @BizzyBee Yes, what is it?

Comment: The issue i was having was resolved when I used the answer from Dipesh but if I put that same answer into setState for slicedLetters inside the getLetterInput function the issue is no longer resolved. I know one shouldnt manipulate state directly. Is using the filter method directly on slicedLetters an example of manipulating state directly?

Answer (score 1):

If a letter is clicked, you can add it to a `clickedLetters` state from within your `getLetterInput`, and then filter through `slicedLetters` like so:

```
const [slicedLetters, setSlicedLetters] = React.useState(["a", "b", "c"]);
const [clickedLetters, setClickedLetters] = React.useState(["a"]);

  <div className="letter_wrapper">
    {slicedLetters.filter((l, i) => {
      if (!clickedLetters.includes(l)) {
        return (
          <p key={i} className="letter_container">
            <span onClick={getLetterInput} className="letter">
              {l}
            </span>
          </p>
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    })}
  </div>
```